Amazon SP-API A+ Content Document Examples javascript WYSIWYG editor which outputs JSON
In the Amazon SP-API A+ Content Document Examples at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/a-content-document-examples the sample screens show a javascript WYSIWYG control which outputs JSON instead of the usual HTML. The format required is documented in https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/selling-partner-api-for-a-content-management#decoratorset.
My question is: does such an editor already exist? If so, then where?
